# Independence of $\partial_t f(t,x)$ and $f(t,x)$ at a fixed time slice?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, linear-independence

Let $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed $\mathcal{E}\bigl(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \bigr)$ be the space of smooth real-valued mappings $f(t,x)$ for $(t,x) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, consider the two linear mappings $T_1, T_2 : \mathcal{E}\bigl(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \bigr) \to \mathcal{E}\bigl(\mathbb{R}^n \bigr)$ defined as
\begin{equation}
T_1(f):=f(t_0,\cdot) \text{ and } T_2(f):= \bigl(\partial_t f \bigr)(t_0, \cdot)
\end{equation}

Then, I wonder if $T_1, T_2$ are linearly independent in the sense that if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy
\begin{equation}
aT_1(f)+bT_2(f)=0 \text{ for all } f \in \mathcal{E}\bigl(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \bigr)
\end{equation}
then, $a=b=0$.

I think this is plausible, but cannot figure out how to prove it rigorously.. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Take $f_1=1$ identically, and $f_2(t,x)=t-t_0$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you for the smart answer to a dumb question..